# How can I declare an array inside a function according to the size of a parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Here is what I have tried:

```
int fun1(vector<int> s)
{ 
    const int n = s.size();
    int arr[n]; //<----want to declare an array of length s.size()
}
```

But this tells me that n is not a constant expression, so I cannot use it to declare the array size. But if I try:

```
int fun1(vector<int> s)
{ 
    const int n = 10;
    int arr[n]; //<-----this works
}
```

then it's fine. Even if I make the vector s of type const, it still won't recognize the size as a constant expression. How do I go about this?

Comment: The size of the vector is determined at runtime.

Comment: why not use a `std::vector<int>`

Comment: You can't declare an automatic storage array whose size is not known at compile time. But you can use an `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Either use vector or look into dynamic allocation.

Comment: Yeah, you can always use `int *arr = new int[n];` to create the array, although a vector would be better.  If you use `new` though, make sure to delete it, `delete arr [];`.

Comment: If you make the const static it should work: `static const int n=10; int arr[n];`. However in practice your code is probably going to relate n to the size of input vector so this will not help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring array by `int arr[N];` the size `N` must be determined in compile-time (except for some compiler extensions which allow you to define them in run-time too). By the way, you can make it:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr (new int [n]);

// ... or ...

std::vector<int> arr(n);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare an array like this

```
int arr[n];
```

the compiler will allocate memory on the stack for it. In this case the C++ standard requires that `n` is known at compile time, i.e. it must be `const`.

The answer to your question is to get the memory from the heap at run time like this:

```
int* arr = new int[n];
```

In this case the memory is allocated at run time and so the value of `n` doesn't need to be known until run time. If you use this approach don't forget to free up the memory when you're done with:

```
delete [] arr;
```

However, as the comments suggest, using a `std::vector<int>` would almost certainly be a better approach. Unless you've got a good reason not to, I'd go with that.

Answer (score 1):

For this, C++ has `std::vector<int>(n)`, which retains most of the semantics of a traditional C array but also adds a lot of benefits (dynamic allocation being one, resizing is another, algorithm support is yet another one). Even when your underlying code requires a C array, you can still use the vector and pass an address of the first element down (they are guaranteed to be contiguous).

Typically, `std::vector` uses heap for underlying storage, so on one hand you are better protected from stack overflows (pun intended), on the other hand, your code now uses dynamic allocation.